# How to save both Chinese and English characters in an SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to save data in MySQL. I want to know if there are any settings that allow me to save strings with English, Chinese, and/or Arabic in the same database field? 
With my current 'utf' setting, all data converts to Chinese characters.

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

'UTF' is the encoding. What you need to adjust is the 'character code'.
"Unicode" provides the range of characters you need. See here:
https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character

The site I'm working on at the moment has a multi-alphabet database and I use a utf8_unicode setting which allows for English, Chinese and Arabic characters.

Comment: If you can understand that post, how about slapping that big edit button, and improve it, so I can understand what he wants.

Comment: @FrankerZ - have done. this editing thing is a first for me!